# Add a file to shelved perforce changelist from another workspace

Tags: perforce

I have a changelist #1234 which I shelved from destop1. It has 5 files but I want to add another file to it say 6.c. The problem is when I do `p4 edit -c 1234 6.c` from desktop2, p4 errors out something like `change 1234 belongs desktop1`. desktop1 and desktop2 are different workspaces under same user. 
How to release changelist 1234 and let me allow to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a second changelist: using the desktop2 workspace, do 'p4 unshelve -s 1234' which will unshelve all the files into your second workspace in the default changelist. Then do 'p4 edit 6.c' on desktop2 and make your changes. Then do 'p4 shelve' and create a new shelved changelist (it will have a different changelist number).

The advantage of this approach is that you still have the first changelist in case you decide that you preferred the first version.

You can test the one changelist, then test the other, and decide which one you want to keep.

When you're all ready, you can submit the changelist you decided that you like, and delete the changelist that you decided not to keep.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating another CL. I read somewhere that there is a way to release perforce CL to another user.